# Java - Referencing objects from another method

Tags: java

This is a little adventure game I'm working on. I'm just trying to create a 3x3 matrix that the player can move around in. But, in the game loop (which doesn't loop yet, I know,) I can't reference the Player or Room objects I created with the init() method. (I have separate class files for Player and Room objects, they work fine.) When I try to run this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Adventure
{
  public final static int maxCol = 2;
  public final static int maxRow = 2;

  public static void init()
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  //instantiate rooms
  final Room[][] maze = new Room[maxCol+1][maxRow+1];
  final Player player = new Player("",1,1);

    for(int i = 0; i <= maxCol; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j <= maxRow; j++)
      {
        maze[i][j] = new Room("room");
      }
    }

  //room names
    maze[0][0].setDesc("Alleyway - West");
    maze[0][1].setDesc("Alleyway - East");
    maze[0][2].setDesc("Back Entrance");
    maze[1][0].setDesc("Back Room");
    maze[1][1].setDesc("Hallway");
    maze[1][2].setDesc("Bar - North");
    maze[2][0].setDesc("Bathroom");
    maze[2][1].setDesc("By An Arcade Machine");
    maze[2][2].setDesc("Bar - South");


  //get player name
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    String nameInput = keyboard.nextLine();

  //create player object
    player.setName(nameInput);
    player.display();
  }


  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    init();
    playGame();
  }

  public static void playGame()
  {
    System.out.print(maze[player.getXPos()][player.getYPos()].getDesc());
  }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
Adventure.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print(maze[player.getXPos()][player.getYPos()].getDesc());
                     ^   symbol:   variable maze   location: class Adventure Adventure.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print(maze[player.getXPos()][player.getYPos()].getDesc());
                          ^   symbol:   variable player   location: class Adventure Adventure.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print(maze[player.getXPos()][player.getYPos()].getDesc());
                                            ^   symbol:   variable player   location: class Adventure 3 errors
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: You declare `maze` and `player` in the `init` method. That is a different scope to `playGame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of scope! Java has particular rules for *how* something can be accessed, depending on *where* it is declared. If you declare something inside a method, then you can only access it inside that method.

```
public void doSomething() {
    String str = "Hello";
    // when doSomething ends, str is lost!
}
```

To solve this, you can *declare* your variable outside of the method, in the global level.

```
String str = "Hello";

public void doSomething() {
    str = "Hello";
}
```

Notice, you've *declared* it outside of the method, but you've *defined* it inside the method.

**Extra Reading**

- The big one is Java [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

Answer (score 0):

Scope of your `maze` variable is limited to the method `init` thus it can't be found in your `playGame` method. Update `init` to return the maze (`Room[][]`) or declare it static. In fact you need to do this for your `player` object too.